# Many to many polymorphic with multiple sub-models sync() method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two sub-model `Category` and `Tag` which extends the `Term` model. Both sub models are have many-to-many polymorphic relation to the `Post` model with pivot table `termables`.

```
// Post.php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'termable', 'termables', 'termable_id', 'term_id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'termable', 'termables', 'termable_id', 'term_id');
    }
}

// Term.php
class Term extends Model
{

}

// Category.php
class Category extends Term
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new TypeScope('category'));
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'termable', 'termables', 'term_id', 'termable_id')
    }
}

// Tag.php
class Tag extends Term
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new TypeScope('tag'));
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'termable', 'termables', 'term_id', 'termable_id')
    }
}
```

When updating the categories and tags together, either tags got removed when updating the categories or categories got removed when updating the tags

Looks like Laravel doesn't check first what is the model of term_id that I've actually declared by `$this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'termable', 'termables', 'termable_id', 'term_id');` before removing and just simply remove everything by `termable_type`.

The possible solution that might works is by separate the pivot table for each sub model into `categorizables` and `taggables` instead of using single `termables` pivot table. But it will makes my database full of pivot tables if I decided to create another set of Term's sub-models.

Any solution how to make it works without separating the pivot table?

Comment: A few information are missing from your question; Please post ``TypeScope`` contents & how you're reaching the issue (having models code only won't help very much)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the `TypeScope` it just a simple scope `$query->where('type', $type);`, as I stated in the question the problem is come when updating tags and categories together, i.e. when using `sync()`.